# google plus login with android redirects back to login screen after button click on attempting to login

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I am trying to make a login into my android app. I have generated the google-services.json with the same package name of the class and copied into the app folder of my application. On attempting to login it shows a dim screeen and thereafter shows a white screen of the the page I am trying to login with.

This is the code snippet from my activity class

```
// Button click listeners
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate End!");
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStart!");
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStart end!");
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop!");

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }


    /**
     * Method to resolve any signin errors
     * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {

        PendingIntent signInIntent  = mConnectionResult.getResolution();
        if (signInIntent != null) {
            if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    mIntentInProgress = true;
                    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mIntentInProgress = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        } else {
            showDialog(DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @Override
      protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
          case DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR:
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(mConnectionResult.getErrorCode())) {
              return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                      mConnectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                  this,
                  RC_SIGN_IN,
                  new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                      Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services resolution cancelled");
                    }
                  });
            } else {
              return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                  .setMessage(R.string.play_services_error)
                  .setPositiveButton(R.string.close,
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services error could not be "
                              + "resolved: " + mConnectionResult.getErrorCode());
                        }
                      }).create();
            }
          default:
            return super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }
      }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
        Log.i(TAG, "See error types in http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html");
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error type: SIGN_IN_REQUIRED");
        }

        if (result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.NETWORK_ERROR ) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error type: NETWORK_ERROR ");
        }

        if (result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE) {
              // An API requested for GoogleApiClient is not available. The device's current
              // configuration might not be supported with the requested API or a required component
              // may not be installed, such as the Android Wear application. You may need to use a
              // second GoogleApiClient to manage the application's optional APIs.
        } else if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            Log.i(TAG, "not IntentInProgress!");
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                Log.i(TAG, "signInAlreadyClicked! Resolving sign error...");
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                // resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed end!");
        //TODO: Sign OUT?
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();

        // Update the UI after signin
        updateUI(true);

    }

    /**
     * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
     * */
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                txtName.setText(personName);
                txtEmail.setText(email);

                // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                // replacing sz=X
                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Button on click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                // Signin button clicked
                signInWithGplus();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                // Signout button clicked
                signOutFromGplus();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                // Revoke access button clicked
                revokeGplusAccess();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            // We only process button clicks when GoogleApiClient is not transitioning
            // between connected and not connected.
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-out from google
     * */
    private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Revoking access from google
     * */
    private void revokeGplusAccess() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                            updateUI(false);
                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
     * */
    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

this is the login button from my page xml file calling the login function to authenticate with google plus

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
Please why is my app not authenticating with google plus sign. Please assist
```